# How to make this form properly inlined?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use sr-only class from bootstrap in order to make an inline form.

It should be something like this:

```
Title              Cost
________________   __________   ______ days at $ ______  X (remove button)
```

I have already searched in lots of places but couldn't find a solution for this.

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Title</label>
        <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Title" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
        <input type="email" value='' class="form-control form-custom" id="name" placeholder="Ime" /> days
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
        <input type="email" value='' class="form-control form-custom" id="name" placeholder="Ime" /> /day
    </div>
</form>
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/quyB6/60/)**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/josangel555/mk3zcffy/ added some labels and made them block.. check it helps..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `.sr-only` has position:absolute style. But you can define you own class. Using margin-top or height. See this example i've made for you, so you can have an idea (See the snippet in fullpage option):

```css
.form-group > .sr-only.control-label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 27px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
    <label for="name" class="control-label">Title</label>
    <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Title" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
    <label class="sr-only control-label" for="exampleInputEmail3">&bnsp;</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Ime" >
      <div class="input-group-addon">days</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
    <label class="sr-only control-label" for="exampleInputEmail3">&bnsp;</label>

    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Ime" >
      <div class="input-group-addon">days</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you Túlio. I had forgotten about the .input-group-addon class.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following CSS.  I added a `class` to the form in order to differentiate it from regular forms and removed the `col` classes from the groups, assuming they float the columns.

```css
.inline-form .form-group {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.inline-form label {
  display: block;
}

.inline-form input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<form class="inline-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Title</label>
        <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Title" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" value='' class="form-control form-custom" id="name" placeholder="Ime" /> days
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" value='' class="form-control form-custom" id="name" placeholder="Ime" /> /day
    </div>
</form>
```